# Unable to delete, download and upload blob to Azure Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've encountered a situation where I'm unable to perform certain operations such as deleting a blob inside a container in my storage account. I've browsed these forums and tried various potential solutions, like giving the right permission or generating a SAS token. I was unable to get it working so I also contacted Azure Support but I wasn't able to get the help I needed.

I'm working on a .NET web application that, when a user is logged in, lists their stored blobs and gives them the possibility to download their files or upload new ones or even delete. I'm able to retreive and display the correct blobs without a problem. When I try to delete or download, I encounter this problem: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Here's a snippet from my code

```
    public static void init(string username){
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(username);

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
        permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;

        // The new shared access policy provides read/write access to the container for 24 hours.
        permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(){
            // To ensure SAS is valid immediately, don’t set the start time.
            // This way, you can avoid failures caused by small clock differences.
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Add | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete 
        });

        // Set the new stored access policy on the container.
        container.SetPermissions(permissions);
    }//init

    public static void deleteBlob(string name){
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
        blob.Delete();
    }//delete
```

I've made sure that the string values represent correct containers and blobs.

I also tried inserting some sort of MIME to my web.config file

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".txt" mimeType="text/plain"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
</staticContent>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's how the method looks in my controller

```
public ActionResult Delete(string name) {
    StorageModel.deleteBlob(name);
    return View(refreshList());
}//delete
```

And here is how it looks on my cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.name  })
```

Comment: Please include the code segment where Azure blob methods are invoked. Based on the error, you are probably using a Web Api and route is not configured properly.

Comment: @Ankit Edited and added my related code from the controller and cshtml file

Comment: Can you try to get the blob URL in your deleteBlob method and see if you're trying to delete correct blob.

Comment: The blob name, container name and storage account is correct (?): https://<snip>.blob.core.windows.net/" + container.Name + "/" + name

Comment: Could you share exception type and stack trace of the exception you see?

Comment: Please check whether you could delete the blob via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer tool. Besides, I'd like to know whether you name blob with **path information** in its name.

Comment: To give an example of how my storage is structured: I have one storage account and I get it through parsing my StorageConnectionString. I have one container named "alican" and inside that I have a .txt file named "test.txt" along with other similar files. I am able to do container.ListBlobs and display the files that I have. On Azure Portal I have all access and can delete/download/upload.

Comment: Also, I seem to be unable to retreive the stack trace error, because I'm always redirected to "http://<snip>.azurewebsites.net/Cloud/Delete/test.txt

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are marking this as correct answer I'm telling you that you kind of messed up OOP.

- make sure you are buiding corectly in the constructor your storage account and your blob container name (init method of yours with username as parameter witch in fact is container name)
- your init method is static, I'm 100% sure you are tryng to delete the file from an incorrect container, container name can be alternated from another StorageModel.init("some_container")
- so make sure you are in the correct container
- before deleting or whatever are you doing check if your file exists

  ```
  public static bool FileExists(string fileName, out int errorCode)
  {
      try
      {
          errorCode = ErrorCode.SUCCESS;
          return container.ListBlobs(fileName, true).Any();
      }
      catch (Exception) //TODO: treat/log exception
      {
          errorCode = ErrorCode.ERROR_LOOKING_FOR_FILE;
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

call this thingy here:

```
public static void deleteBlob(string name){
    //exist file
    int errCode = 0;
    if (FileExists(name, out errCode))
    {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            blob.Delete();
            return;
    }
    //do something if error
}
```

> But the biggest problem of yours is that static object StorageModel,
>   even this is what you are looking for, and will fix the problem, this isn't the right way to do
>   it

```
public ActionResult Delete(string name) {
    StorageModel.Init("Correct Container Name")
    StorageModel.deleteBlob(name);
    return View(refreshList());
}
```

Comment: This is a small project not intended for real life scenarios, and my Azure account is very limited. Potential "visitors" have to share the same storage account, container and files. I'm sure that I'm not entering wrong filenames or container names as I can retreive and display them for the user.